# Calculation in Numbers to figure out the date 5 business days from another date

Tags: numbers

I have been going around and around but haven't quite grasped some of the key formula concepts.

I have a start date and want to add 5 business days to it. Start date + 5 doesn't take into account that one or two of those days may be a weekend.

How would you set that up?

Comment: Use the weekday function and test the days to see if they are workdays or not... may need an if() or and() - have not thought about it yet...

Comment: I have thought conceptually about adding the 5 days one at a time, then testing to see if it the result was a Saturday. If it was, add an extra two days. But it is inelegant and will probably pull an error.  I think there is probably an elegant solution. I am just not a math/code wiz enough to figure it out!

Answer (score 4):

Days and dates are always messy, so whenever possible, one should try to use someone else's hard work. In this case, Apple have done it for us.

Say your date is in B2, example forumla to add five *business* days:
`WORKDAY(B2,5,)`

You can read more about its usage and find the other date-related functions available in Apple's [Numbers Functions Reference](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/8.1/#/ffa55f9592).

Comment: And the same function exists in excel.... plus 1 from me.